# passing javascript variable to php in cakephp 2 view

Tags: php, html, image, cakephp, web

I am trying to pass a javascript variable into a php code in the view file of the cakephp 2.

```
for (id in response) {

    var book = response[id];

    if (typeof(book.thumbnail_url) != "undefined") {
        var x= book.thumbnail_url; 

        <?php   
            $file11 = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'book_images';
            define('DIRECTORY', $file11);

            $content = file_get_contents($abc);
            file_put_contents(DIRECTORY . '/'.$isbn.'.jpg', $content);
        ?>
    }
}
```

i am trying to pass the value of `x` in the `file_get_contents` function in place of `$abc` so that it could save the image coming from the javascript's URL accordingly.

EDIT::

```
     for (id in response) {


                                   var book = response[id];

                                        if (typeof(book.thumbnail_url) != "undefined") {
                                        var x= book.thumbnail_url; 
                                         $.ajax({
                                           type: "POST",
                                           url: '/BookSearchs/test',
                                           data: {'yourX':x}
                                        }).done(function(result) {
                                            alert("yes");
                                        }).fail(function() {
                                            alert("no");
                                        });
                                      }



                                     }
```

This is what i wrote after implementing the answers i got . But Everytime it pops up "no". Here BookSearchs is my controller and test is my function inside it.

EDIT 2:

```
function handleResponse(response) {
    var target = '';

    for (id in response) {


        var book = response[id];

        if (typeof(book.thumbnail_url) != "undefined") {
            var x = book.thumbnail_url;



            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "BookSearchs/test",



                    data: {
                        myVal: x
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        alert('AjaX Success')
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('AjaX Failed')
                    }
                })

                .done(function() {
                    alert('AjaX Done!');
                });
        }



    }

    return true;

}
```

Currently this is what i've  have done so far , the form method did not work out . It was redirecting me to another page . Anyways this is my current code . And 'test' is the my function inside the controller where i want to access the `myVal` value using POST . Also i have this question do i need to create a physical file for test in order to make the ajax function work, because if i delete the `test.ctp` file then the ajax starts giving the fail message . So for now i have created a physical test.file in the `BookSearchs` folder in the view , although it's empty in order to make the ajax function work . I am having a doubt whether my `Url` in Ajax is wrong or i am not accessing the values properly in the controller.

Comment: I can show you how to send it to the controller if you want

Comment: ya .. that'd be good as well

Comment: that was actually my initial plan .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a proper way to do that in theory. But, sometime we might need this.

Before we proceed to this way, you might need to think other technologies such as NodeJs (e.g `fs.readFileSync`)

Basically, you can't directly do that. Because, JavaScript run on client side and PHP is run on sever side.

Anyway, there might be a few tweak to do that. But, this approach might be slow and it depends on how many loop you making.

```
for (id in response) {
    var book = response[id];
    if (typeof(book.thumbnail_url) != "undefined") {
        var x= book.thumbnail_url; 
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/yourcontroller/route',
           data: {'yourX':x}
        }).done(function(result) {
            //if success, execute other code
        }).fail(function() {
            //DO other if fail
        });
    }
 }
```

Then, read this value in your controller

```
$xValue = $_POST['yourX'];

$file11 = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'book_images';
define('DIRECTORY', $file11);
$content = file_get_contents($xValue);
file_put_contents(DIRECTORY . '/'.$isbn.'.jpg', $content);
//do some checking success or fail
//I will assume success
$status = 'success';
echo json_encode(['status'=>$status]);
```

Comment: I think that the problem with ajax in this case is that it interact just with the same view, I mean that if we can't  send a `Js` variable to the controller & then send it to another view, this is the issue with ajax, we must stay in the view;

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi No need to go to other view. It can be done in same view.

Comment: So it depends of your needs ^^

Comment: While you are correct about the problem, the PHP example is kinda problematic, security wise (it allows to read arbitrary files and write them to a public directory), and best practice wise (in CakePHP you should not access superglobals directly, and controllers should never echo data).

Comment: @ndm I agreed on that. But, I'm showing the way as a snippet. Anyway, thank for your information and will deploy it on upcoming answers. :)

Comment: i am getting confused with the URL part ..  "url: '/BookSearchs/test'"... This is what i've written where BookSearchs is my controller and test is a function inside of that controller.

Comment: You can create another function inside your controller (e.g fileContent). Don't forget to set '$this->autoRender = false;'

Answer (score 0):

Usally I use a Trick to pass *JS* variable to a *CakePhp Controller*(php variable). Actionly I create a `form` that contain a hidden `input`, I'll also put the link of the page that will receive the php variable.

**.ctp**

```
 <?=
$this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>' .__('Export'),
'javascript:myFunction();',
array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-app  dispatch',  'id' => 'dispatch_packages',
'style'=>'margin-right:0px;background: #f39c12;color:white;',
'disabled' => 'false'));
?>
<form id="sampleForm" name="sampleForm" style="display: none" method="post" action="<?= $this->Url->build([
                        'controller' => 'YourController',
                        'action' => 'youraction']) ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="variable" id="variable" value="">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var jsVar=0;
    function  myFunction()
    {

        document.sampleForm.variable.value = jsVar;

        document.forms["sampleForm"].submit();
    }
```

I used it with the **CakePhp 3.x** framework & it's working very fine. You have just to write the url with the **CakePhp 2.x** Syntax.

Don't hesitate to comment my answer if you'll have any difficulties to apply it. 
**Good Luck !**

Comment: how am i supposed to access the value in the controller

Comment: @HarjeevSingh `$phpVariable=$this->request->data('variable');`

Comment: not yet.. anyways i have a question if i make a function in the controller apart from the index function , is it necessary to make the physical file as well .

Comment: @HarjeevSingh You're talking about a view file related to the function ? If Yes, then no it's not necessary !